# Finding Complex Solutions?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers

I have the question "Find all complex solutions of
$(z-1)^2=2-2i\sqrt3$".

My doubt is that I don't know if the question is as simple as it seems to me or if there's more to it.

Should I just solve it usually and get $z=1\pm\sqrt{-2i\sqrt3+2}$ or is there more to it that I'm just being oblivious about?

I'm sorry in advance for any ignorance from my part

Comment: have you learned De Moivre's theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking to the square formula of a complex number :
$$(a + i b)^2 = a^2 - b^2 + 2 i a b$$
we deduce that :
$$2 - 2 i \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3}^2 - (-1)^2 + 2 i (-1) \sqrt{3} = \left(\sqrt{3} - i\right)^2$$
then the equation :
$$(z - 1)^2 = 2 - 2 i \sqrt{3}$$
becomes :
$$(z - 1)^2 = \left(\sqrt{3} - i\right)^2$$
then :
$$z - 1 = \sqrt{3} - i \text{ or } z - 1 = - \sqrt{3} + i$$
And finally :
$$z = 1 + \sqrt{3} - i \text{ or } z = 1 - \sqrt{3} + i$$

Answer (score 3):

It is neater to notice that the RHS is the square of $\sqrt3-i$.

Then $z=1\pm (\sqrt3-i)$.

In general it is best with such questions to try to get an answer in the form $a+bi$.

Answer (score 0):

$(z - 1)^2 = 2 - 2\sqrt 3 i = 4(\cos -\frac {\pi}{3} + i\sin -\frac {\pi}{3})\\
z-1 = \sqrt {2 - 2\sqrt 3 i} = \pm 2 (\cos -\frac {\pi}{6} + i\sin -\frac {\pi}{6}) = \sqrt 3 - i, -\sqrt 3 + i\\
z =  \sqrt 3 +1 - i, -\sqrt 3 +1 +i$